# Casperjs - how to send a javascript object to a module

Tags: module, casperjs

I am using casperjs to write a test suite for my GUI. I have split out my code into modules which are called by the main script.

I can't seem to pass in a javascript object to my module. I am reading a json config file, converting it to an object and then I'd like to pass that to my module.

testSuite.js (main script):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var test1 = require('../jstests/admin/auth');
var config = {};

casper.start('http://localhost:8080/ipiadmin', function() {});

var fs = require('fs');
configFile = fs.read('./jstests/admin/config.json');
casper.then(function() {
  config = JSON.parse(configFile);
});
casper.then(function() {
  this.echo("username: " + config.username);  // outputs the name correctly
});

test1.runTest(casper, config, "testme");

casper.run(function() {
    this.test.done();
    this.test.renderResults(true);
});
```

auth.js (module)

```
 exports.runTest = function auth(casper, config, test) {

  /*** Login ***/  
  casper.waitFor(function() {
    this.echo("test: " + test);  // "test: testme"
    this.echo("username: " + config.username);  // "username: undefined"
    return true;
  });

  return true;
}
```

config.json (configuration file)

```
{
  "username": "something",
  "password": "secret"
}
```

when I run the above, I get:

```
Test file: jstests/admin/testSuite.js                                           
username: something
--- Running auth ---
test: testme
username: undefined
```

I'm guessing that I could probably pass the file contents as a string and then convert it to an object in the module, but that doesn't seem quite right to me.

Has anyone else tried this? Successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to wrap `test1.runTest(casper, config, "testme");` in a `Casper#then` statement, like this.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var test1 = require('../jstests/admin/auth');
var config = {};

casper.start('http://localhost:8080/ipiadmin', function() {});

var fs = require('fs');
configFile = fs.read('./jstests/admin/config.json');
casper.then(function() {
  config = JSON.parse(configFile);
});
casper.then(function() {
  this.echo("username: " + config.username);  // outputs the name correctly
});

// ---
casper.then(function() {
  test1.runTest(casper, config, "testme");
});
// ---

casper.run(function() {
  this.test.done();
  this.test.renderResults(true);
});
```

Tested using PhantomJS 1.9.1 and CasperJS 1.1.0(Master branch).